# Unsupervised Learning, Different Techniques & Queries

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, topic-modeling, unsupervised-learning, doc2vec

I have to predict based on the data, which disaster management team should have responded to the accident - Police/Rescue/Fire Brigade/Ambulance etc.

There are several part to the problem -

1. A unique ID - (a combination of number)
2. Text data of multiple sentences for each ID,

   > ex: The damage caused is due to hailstorm. The people were not
   >   following rescue instructions and were careless. The damage is high.
   >   -In total 50k different ID with text
3. Several structured data fields - like location, type, severity etc. - total 400 variables

Method to Solve the problem:

1. Taken the text data and ID and calculated TFIDF, cosine similarity, Doc2Vec, Topic Model

Now I have to merge the structured data and unstructured data to make clusters. As it is an unsupervised learning, not sure how to club all above to make some meaning out of data.

In total, I have now - 400 variables, 10000 scores value from TFIDF, but I am:

- Not sure how to connect cosine similarity with data frame
- Not sure how to use Doc2Vec for cluster
- Not sure how to utilize Topic Models

Final Goal - To create clusters which can be studied to differentiate that if a ID contains certain keywords it should go to particular management team - for example: theft/murder/robbery - all should be one cluster and I can associate Police with that cluster

Comment: Hi @Dr.Chuck and welcome to SO :-) It's unclear to me what you are asking, can you please try to rephrase your question?

Comment: questions reframed. Goal is to create clusters using structured and unstructured data. There is no target variable, hence unsupervised learning.

Comment: Are you sure you need to create clusters as an interim step? If end goal is "from this info, classify best responder", and you do in fact have reliable historic info on proper responder, you may just want to do supervised classification. (You may need to be careful, of course, not to include post-incident refinements of the record which strongly hint or reveal the "right answer".)

Comment: @gojomo yes, I am pretty sure that I have to create clusters. Think it in a way that the historical responses are wrong. My objective here is to compare the two, what happened in the past to what should have done.

Comment: If you have expert-annotated "correct" responses, or even just mostly-correct "actual" responses, you could train a classifier. And the cases it gets "wrong", in either case, or those for which it shows lowest-confidence, are likely to be interesting "edge cases" deserving further human review (and perhaps annotation cleanup). (I can see separate clustering as perhaps being interesting for exploratory purposes, but not strictly necessary for either potential automation, or ML-driven review of edge cases, both of which can be done with just a classifier.)

Comment: Do you need the 400 other variables? If you do not, you could just use Latent Dirichlet Allocation (probably the best known topic model), which would find the latent topics in your texts (one or more "clusters" of words could be assigned to the police, etc, and you can then predict the likelihood of a new text belonging to a topic). Doc2vec in combination with TFIDF might not be the best methods to use. If you want to feed back "corrected" classifications to your model, you might want to check out [active learning](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/active-learning).

Comment: @jhl I am thinking to extract some features from topic model and then use them along with structured data to create clusters. Let's say, I have the word theft/fire/robbery/hailstorm - I am trying to figuring out how to assign score to these variables as TFIDF score is low given the large size of corpus

Comment: @gojomo - I got your point. I will run two models, one supervised and one unsupervised to see how the results relates between the two. Though for unsupervised there will be 15000 features/variables, what will be the best technique to work, Can i give this much input to K means?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: @gojomo, not tried yet, working on structured data now, it might take a week to get in a position where can run both of them. Will let you know once it is completed